# Alesha, Who Smiles at Death, and cards with a * as their power

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

So my question is if I have [Alesha, Who Smiles at Death](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Alesha%2C%20Who%20Smiles%20at%20Death) on the battlefield can I use her ability to bring back a creature where * is the cards power, for example [Kolaghan Forerunners](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kolaghan%20Forerunners)?

Comment: There's a ruling for Kolaghan Forerunners in Gatherer answering this very question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Forerunners have what is called Characteristic-Defining Ability, and those function in all zones. So you can only return them with Alesha if you have less than 3 creatures on the battlefield.

> **208.2a** The card may have a characteristic-defining ability that sets its power and/or toughness according to some stated condition. (See rule 604.3.) Such an ability is worded “[This creature’s] [power or toughness] is equal to . . .” or “[This creature’s] power and toughness are each equal to . . .” **This ability functions everywhere**, even outside the game. If the ability needs to use a number that can’t be determined, including inside a calculation, use 0 instead of that number.

Comment: ok, that's kind of how I figured it would play out but wanted to makes sure. Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to point out that not all creatures with * as their power have characteristic-defining abilities, and fall under rule 208.2b. For example, Sewer Nemesis.

Comment: @HaoYe I'm not sure offhand, but it looks like Sewer Nemesis *does* have a characteristic-defining ability, just one that doesn't do anything without a player being chosen. Not that the distinction matters in practice.